# Find countours on a dark background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose, I have a dark image on a white background. For example, the image below:

[image]

With the code below, I can easily extract its countors

```
import imutils
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = imutils.resize(image, width = 64)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 7)
# initialize the outline image, find the outermost
# contours then draw
# it
outline = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
x=cv2.drawContours(outline, [cnts], -1, 255, -1)
```

This would give me the image below

[image: easy image, white background, good contrast between foreground and background]

However, let us try a more difficult image, like below

[image: difficult image]

whenever I run such a code using the image above, I find the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "segment_img.py", line 16, in <module>
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It obviously does not find any countors. However, I am using adaptive threshold which is supposed to work.

What can I change in my code so I could make both images having their corresponding contours?

Comment: your focus should be to capture better images. If that's not possible you can try to normalize the image by finding minimum and maximum intensity and shift+rescale the whole image so that min becomes 0 and max becomes 255. Another possibility can be histogram equalization on the grayscale image. You might want to try other contrast enhancement techniques as well. But min/max normalization is simple and maybe the best you can expect for these kind of images.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your suggestion. The images are normalized, the min and max are always 0 and 255 respectively. It seems that Otsu's threshold works. I will post my answer but other suggestions will also be welcome. Thanks again.

Comment: I do not believe that the min and max of your second image are 0 and 255 (unless there is one pixel somewhere that cannot be seen -- if so, some filtering/morphology would take care of that). Please check and show your min and max for the second image.  See skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity() to stretch the image's dynamic range based upon min and max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` we may use `cv2.threshold` with `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` argument (and `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`):

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
```

`cv2.THRESH_OTSU` uses [Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) for automatic image thresholding.

---

Code sample:

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image = imutils.resize(image, width = 64)
#thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 7)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
# initialize the outline image, find the outermost
# contours then draw
# it
outline = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype="uint8")
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
x = cv2.drawContours(outline, [cnts], -1, 255, -1)
```

---

Result:
[image]

---

It's not a magic that works in all cases, and it's also possible to select parameters for `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` that works for the specific case.

Otsu's method usually works where there are two main distinct gray levels (with some deviation from the mean of each distinct level).

Comment: I think the problem with the adaptive threshold was that the constant offset (the last value in the parameter list) was wiping out all the values in the image.

Comment: I was just writing what you said. Thks!

Answer (score 1):

The Otsu's threshold did more or less what I need.

```
def prepare_image(image_name):

    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image=cv2.resize(image, (28,28), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    ret2,thresh = v2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # initialize the outline image, find the outermost
    # contours, then draw
    # it
    outline = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), 
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
    cv2.drawContours(outline, [cnts], -1, 255, -1)


    x=np.zeros(outline.shape)
    x[outline==0]=255

    return x
```

The outputs of the two images are more or less like these:

[image]
[image]

Not excactly perfect. I am open to other suggestions.